# Push State - How to update relative links

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use push state to update the url when loading ajax content. The urls changed via push state lead to some directories deeper.

I also have other normal relative links in the website and unfortunately they don't update. So if I click an url after loading the content and changing it via push state, the link tries to load the file one directory deeper...

I need to use relative urls, so do you have other ideas?

Edit:

for example i have this url:

http://www.example.com/site/profile

i change it to this one via push state for example:

http://www.example.com/site/profile/information

And i have a link that leads relative to another file, for example:

```
<a href="../anotherSite">
```

The Problem is that the relative links are not updated, so after the url was changed, the link leads to: http://www.example.com/site/anotherSite and not http://www.example.com/anotherSite like it should...

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Or at least elaborate a bit more on your problem? It's very hard to tell what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally after some hours of search I found a solution and after asking that question, too.

I set a base url, so I dont have to update the urls.

(base html tag)